# CodeIgniter appending to the beginning of the view when it shouldn't be

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I call regularDashboard(), it appends to the beginning of my view. In my view I'm calling $reg from inside a formatted style. So it shouldn't be echoing out at the beginning of the view... Any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
public function dcr() {
        // pass all dashboard accesses through this function
        $username = $this->session->userdata("username");
        $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('username' => $username));
        $userType = $this->session->userdata('userType');
        if ($userType == 'regular') {
                foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                    $data = array('reg' => $this->regularDashboard(), 'firstname' => $row->firstname);
                    $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
} public function regularDashboard () {
            $userid = $this->session->userdata('userid');
            $results = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
            foreach ($results->result() as $row) {
                if($userid != $row->userid) {
                    echo $row->firstname . " " . $row->lastname;
                    echo "<form method='GET' action='processing/lib/process-send-friend-request.php?'>";
                    echo '<input name="accepted" type="submit" value="Send User Request" /><br />';
                    echo '<input name="AddedMessage" placeholder="Add a message?" type="textbox" />';
                    echo '<br>Select Friend Type: ' . '<br />Full: ';
                    echo '<input name="full_friend" type="checkbox"';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $row->idusers . '" />';
                    echo '</form>';
                    echo "<br /><hr />";
                } elseif ($userid == $row->userid) {
                    echo $row->firstname . " " . $row->lastname;
                    echo "<br />";
                    echo "You all are currently friends";
                }
       }
}
```

Comment: Did you get this figured out? Please choose an answer if either Damien or I have helped.

Comment: I placed the code in the view like what Damien said to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are buffered. When you echo something directly in a controller, it is sent *before* the buffer is flushed (therefore before the output containing the view is sent to the browser), that's why it appears before anything.

You shouldn't to this (sending a direct output/echoing something outside of views), you risk getting into troubles as soon as you use anything related to headers (redirect, cookies, CI's sessions...)

#### UPDATE:

To fix it, just assign all those string to a variable (as jeff showed), and send that to the view:

```
$data['form'] = $row->firstname . " " . $row->lastname;
$data['form'] .= "<form method='GET' action='processing/lib/process-send-friend-request.php?'>";

$this->load->view('formview',$data);
```

There, you just echo $form and you'll have all your strings output correctly.

**EDIT :**
all above if you're inside a Controller. If you're in a Model, just assign everything to a variable and return it to the Controller:

```
function regularDashboard()
{
  $form = $row->firstname . " " . $row->lastname;
  $form .= "<form method='GET' action='processing/lib/process-send-friend-request.php?'>";
  return $form;
}
```

In the controller:

```
$data['form'] = $this->model->regularDashboard();
$this->load->view('formview',$data);
```

If you allow me, I'd suggest writing the form *directly into the view*, without the hassle (and the structural error) of creating something that's supposed to be "presentation" outdside of views.

Comment: So, when something is presentational, i can code it in the view? no matter if its Ci or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "if its CI or not"? Anyway, yeah, anything related to "views", or how the page will be in the browser, _should_ be done in views. Business logic should be done in models, and controllers should manage both.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your issue is the use of `echo` from within `regularDashboard()`. Try setting a variable that contains the `form` markup and return it instead of using `echo`.

Here is an example:

```
function regularDashboard()
{
    $html  = "";
    $html .= "<form>";

    //Append the rest of the form markup here

    return $html;
}
```